# Is it legal to push the rook with the king when castling?

Tags: rules, castling

I've gotten into the habit of pushing the rook over to the appropriate square using my king; that is, I take my king into my hand, I take it to the outer edge of the board, then push the rook to its right place using the king figure. Then, I place my king on the correct square.

I've not played in an over-the-board tournament before, and if I ever do so I'd like to know whether this is okay or whether it's a habit I need to lose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as you -

- only use one hand
- touch the king first
- don't do it in such a way as to disturb the opponent

then it is fine.